# hugo serve content inside .well-known folder

Tags: hugo, gitlab-pages

Third party application which I'm trying to integrate, asking to put a file inside a `.well-known` folder. how can I make that file accessible from URL? (`example.com/.well-known/token.txt`). site is deployed as a gitlab page. every attempt I tried gives 404 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put your ".well-known" folder inside the "static" folder it should get deployed to the root of your website as you expect.

Comment: you saved my day

Comment: My site redirects to my 404 page. Do I need to do something to expose the .well-known folder?
It works when I put it in the root of the site.